# Python Dictionary how to

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'm trying to create a dictionary in python where If i type in CS101
I'll receive the data room number 3004, Instructor Haynes, and meeting time is 8:00 am. I'm not 100% certain how to let the instructor, room number, and meeting time come up. This is what i have so far.

```
def get_menu_choice():
    print('Course number, and their value')
    print('-------------------------------')
    print('1. Look up the key CS101')
    print('2. Quit the program')
    print()
    #understand what the user wants
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    # make sure it gives you the correct information

    while choice < look_up or choice > Quit:
        choice = int(input( 'Enter a valid choice: '))

    # return the choice you picked
    return choice
```

Not exactly sure where to go from here... or where to put in my data. I want to be able to type in CS101, and have the room number, meeting time, and instructor come up

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of Object Oriented Programming?

Comment: Even that piece of code is invalid. I think you seriously should consider going back to basics of Python. I would like to recommend: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python

Comment: ok, accepting user to enter choice 1. but where is data for room number and other things?

Comment: Do you know how to create a `dictionary`? Do you know how to create a `tuple`? If yes, please show your code where you create the dictionary. If not, please reread the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary in python is just a set of `key` -> `value` pairs;

```
"CS101" -> "Library, Colonel Mustard, Candlestick"
"CS102" -> "Conservatory, Reverend Green, Revolver"
"CS103" -> "Ballroom, Professor Plum, Lead Pipe"
```

How you store the `keys` and `values` is up to you, you could have them as `strings`, like above, or you could store them as `tuples`/`arrays`, or as custom `objects` - it's up to you.

In python you create a dictionary using the `{key: value, key: value, ...}`  syntax - it is detailed in the standard library documentaion [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

You can additionally add new opjects to your dictionary using the `my_dictionary[key] = value` assignment syntax (which will overwrite and old value at that same key).

For example, turning what we had before into this `dict` format;

```
course_plan = dict() # create a new empty dictionary
course_plan = {}     # or we can do it like this.

course_plan["CS101"] = "Library, Colonel Mustard, Candlestick"
course_plan["CS102"] = "Conservatory, Reverend Green, Revolver"
course_plan["CS103"] = "Ballroom, Professor Plum, Lead Pipe"
```

And then you access the entries in the dictionary like this:

```
print course_plan["CS101"] # This prints: "Library, Colonel Mustard, Candlestick"
```

So you'll need to create a dictionary like this, and then inside your function access it.

Of course you could take it a little further; the `value`s in the dictionary could be `arrays`/`tuples` of the data;

```
course_plan["CS101"] = ["Library", "Colonel Mustard", "Candlestick"]
course_plan["CS101"] = ("Library", "Colonel Mustard", "Candlestick")
```

Or as in the other answer they could be dictionaries containing some metadata;

```
course_plan["CS101"] = {"location": "Library", "suspect": "Colonel Mustard", "weapon": "Candlestick"}
```

Or you could indeed create your own class to store the data, and additionally displace it nicely;

```
class MyObject(object):
  def __init__(self, location, suspect, weapon):
    self.location = location
    self.suspect = suspect
    self.weapon = weapon

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s in the %s with the %s" %(self.suspect, self.location, self.weapon)

course_plan["CS101"] = MyObject("Professor Plum", "Ballroom", "Rope")

print course_plan["CS101"] # Professor Plum in the Ballroom with the Rope
```

Answer (score 0):

A lightweight way to implement this would be to use a nested dictionary:

```
d = {}

d['CS101'] = {'room number': 3004, 'instructor': 'Haynes', 'time': '8:00 am'}

print d
{'CS101': {'instructor': 'Haynes', 'time': '8:00 am', 'room number': 3004}}

print d['CS101']['time']
Out[4]: '8:00 am'
```

Then you just need to print every item in the dictionary. You could also use a class, but I would get a handle on dictionaries before moving onto classes/OOP.

Answer (score 0):

**Best to read Python basic dictionary tutorial.**

**How to Create dictionary:**

Use `dict()` create empty dictionary

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
```

or

```
>>> d1 = {}
>>> type(d1)
<type 'dict'>
```

**Assign and get key and values**:

```
>>> d = {"Key1":"Value1"}
>>> d
{'Key1': 'Value1'}
>>> d["Key2"] = "Value2"
>>> d
{'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key1': 'Value1'}
>>>
```

**Dictionary with value of key is dictionary**

Following demo is to get key, room number and meeting time from the user.

**code**:

```
result = {}
u_key = raw_input("Enter key:")
room_no = raw_input("Enter room number:")
meeting_time = raw_input("Meeting time:")
result[u_key] = {"room_number":room_no, "meeting_time":meeting_time}

print "\nFinal Result:", result
```

**Output**:

```
Enter key:C001
Enter room number:R001
Meeting time:12:30 PM

Final Result: {'C001': {'room_number': 'R001', 'meeting_time': '12:30 PM'}}
```

**Note**:

Use raw_input() for Python 2.x

Use input() fro Python 3.x